# Conditional concatenation per sample in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

My model consists of just an input with two heads and three hidden layers, all linear. But the tricky part is this: my input is a composite of two one-dimensional vectors of size 64, which I pass through another layer of 64 neurons for each half. Then I concatenate them into a single vector of 128, and process all the remaining layers as usual. However, I want to make the concatenation conditional, and change the order depending on that condition. As such, I need to check before the concatenation for every sample in each batch, which is something I have no idea how to do.

I am using a generator which yields the inputs as a single vector, and using the Functional API in Keras I select each half to pass through the first hidden layer. But is the conditional concatenation part in which I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you have a problem that could be easily solved with a fully connected layer. Not efficient, though, but let's not start with optimizing.

Make a copy of your 128 vector input. Multiply the original with your condition (encoded as 0/1) and the copy with 1-condition. Concatenate the two, and feed them to a frozen FC layer of size 256x128. The top half is the identity matrix (128x128), the bottom half is a permutation matrix (each row and column has one 1.0 value).

The basic idea is that multiplying with 0.0 discards a value and multiplying by 1.0 keeps a value. Your frozen FC layer is quite sparse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question: a condition would affect the entire batch or only one sample at a time? Because if I can use a condition between the layers, it's just a matter of changing the order depending on the condition in-place.

Comment: @underwater: The idea is that we encode the condition as a 256-element vector and multiply that vector which each input. That's how we turn a condition into math. You still need to provide a new value for that condition on each sample, if that's what you require.